# 英語が残っている: ヘルプ センター > 私のアカウント

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語, ヘルプ

「ヘルプ センター > 私のアカウント」に英語が残っています。具体的には以下（２箇所）。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

またWhy is the system asking me...をクリックした先のページも英語が残っています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

> [Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited)

※「私のアカウント」から「質問にあたって」に[移動されています](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251102)

日本語版：未訳

Answer (score 1):

とりあえず、[Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited) の日本語訳案を出しておきます。

---

### 別の質問を投稿する前に1日以上の休憩をシステムに求められるのはなぜですか？

質問をするというのは時に難しいことですが、私たちはこのサイトで全てのユーザーができる限り有意義に過ごせるよう願っています。あなたは既に数件の質問を投稿していて、そのうちいくつかはコミュニティーでの評判があまりよくないようです。このサイトについて詳しく見つつ、少し休憩するよい機会です。

この時間を過ごす最善の方法は、興味がある[タグ](/tags)が付けられた質問を得票順に並べ、プラス票が多いものを見てみることです。

> [image: 得票順に並び換えた質問]

これらの質問にはいくつか共通点があることに気付きます。

- 最大限の筆記力で、文法や句読点が正確に使用されている
- 解決を必要とする明確な問題が述べられていて、その問題を他の人が再現するために必要な関連情報が全て含まれている
- 明確かつ説明的なタイトル（質問形式である事が多い）が付けられている
- 単刀直入で、読みやすく理解しやすい

他の質問を見てまわった後は、あなたが以前にした質問に戻って改善のための編集をしてしてください。また、回答可能な質問を探して、すばらしい回答を行なうこともおすすめします。多くの質問がすでになされ、回答されていますから、[検索](/help/searching)に慣れることにも時間をさいてください。

未読であれば、[良い質問をする方法](/help/how-to-ask)と、[どのような質問を避けるべきか](/help/dont-ask)についてのアドバイスをお読みください。

***このブロックは一時的なものですが、システムにはさらに長期間のブロックが存在します。*** 私たちは一度落ち着いてより多くの手引きを提供することで、システムがあなたのアカウントからの質問を長期に受け付けなくなるのを避けようとしています。可能な限り時間をとって、あなたが以前にした質問に戻り改善してください。

またすぐに質問できるようになりますが、質問する前に確実に問題を調査し、本当に行き詰まった時にだけ質問するようにしてください。質問が必要になった時に私たちが提供した手引きを忘れなければ、誰もがより良い経験をすることでしょう。